# Estoy haciendo un delay en un Key Event en java

Tags: java, hilos, objeto, game, keypressevent

Estoy recreando el SpaceInvaders en Java y quiero hacer un delay entre misil y misil.

```
    @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT&&n.boom==0) {
        left=true;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT&&n.boom==0) {
        right=true;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE&&n.boom==0) {
        space=true;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left=false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right=false;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        space=false;
    }

    
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

En mi codigo la variable space es una variable booleana que cuando es true crea un nuevo objeto misil en otra función.
El código funciona en un while(true) por lo que si hago un thread.sleep() se va a parar todo el juego.

Comment: Esta es la versión de stack overflow en español. por favor, traduce tu pregunta, o mígrala al homólogo anglosajón :)

Comment: Ay perdoname, ahora mismo la migro. Muchas gracias

Comment: Una forma de evitar que dispare demasiado rápido es guardar el instante en el que haces el disparo y no dejar mandar otro hasta que el momento actual menos el momento guardado sea superior al intervalo de tiempo que quieras configurar.